# Is it normal Indy behavior to stop working when I open Windows' WiFi menu?

Tags: delphi, tcp, windows-10, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I write this minimal example to test a strange behavior I found in Indy.

I have a TCP server and client, and I send 50 x 2MB buffers from client to server. If I open the Windows WiFi menu (the one you use to connect to a network), my TCP transfer is stopped for a few seconds and then continues. This is not good for my app, because I cannot use read timeouts.

Is something wrong with Indy? Or my code? Or Windows? Or is it something else? Can I fix it somehow?

I have uploaded a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ws1Y4B2WyzU) to demonstrate this issue in action.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer,
  IdContext, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdGlobal;

type
  TClientThread = class(TThread)
  private
    Socket: TIdIOHandlerSocket;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ASocket: TIdIOHandlerSocket);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Server: TIdTCPServer;
    Client: TIdTCPClient;
    BStart: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure BStartClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure LogEvent(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_USER;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//---- Client -----------------------------------------------------------------

constructor TClientThread.Create(ASocket: TIdIOHandlerSocket);
begin
 inherited Create;
 Socket:= ASocket;
end;

procedure TClientThread.Execute;
var I, bSize: Integer;
    Buff: TIdBytes;
begin
 bSize:= 2000000;
 SetLength(Buff, bSize+4);
 Move(bSize, Buff[0], 4);
 for I:= 1 to 50 do begin
  Socket.Write(Buff, bSize+4);
 end;
end;

//---- Server -----------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TForm1.ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var Cmd: Cardinal;
    Buff: TIdBytes;
    I: Integer;

 procedure SendString(const AStr: String);
 var Tmp: String;
 begin
  Tmp:= AStr;
  SendMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_USER, WPARAM(@Tmp), 0);
 end;

begin
 SendString('Server START.');
 I:= 0;
 try
  repeat
   Cmd:= AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadUInt32(False);
   if Cmd = $FFFFFFFF then SendString('Srv: keep alive')
    else if Cmd <> 0 then begin
     Inc(I);
     SendString('Srv read '+IntToStr(I)+': '+IntToStr(Cmd)+' bytes');
     if Length(Buff) < Cmd then SetLength(Buff, Cmd);
     AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadBytes(Buff, Cmd, False);
     SendString('Srv read done.');
    end;
  until Cmd = 0;
 finally
  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
  SendString('Server STOP.');
 end;
end;

//---- Form -------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Server.Bindings.Clear;
 Server.Bindings.Add.SetBinding(<the host>, <the port>);
 Server.Active:= True;
 Client.Host:= <a host>;
 Client.Port:= <a port>;
 Client.Connect;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 Client.Disconnect;
 Server.Active:= False;
end;

procedure TForm1.BStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TClientThread.Create(Client.Socket);
end;

procedure TForm1.LogEvent(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
 Memo1.Lines.Add(PString(Msg.WParam)^.Substring(0));
end;

end.
```

**Edit:**

I found that

- the problem persist even with the NetCom7 library.
- the blocking period it is greatly reduced (about 1s) if I try the app on another machine.

Comment: Try to set `BoundIP` of `TIdCPClient` as well. If not set then the `TIdCPClient` will use OS default network card for network connection. And since opening WiFi menu forces Windows to update the list of available network cards it may also delay the response from Windows telling Indy which is the default network connection that should be used. So I'm guessing that bounding `TIdTCPClient`t to specific network card would avoid that. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @SilverWarior to what IP should I bound the `TIdTCPClient` ?

Comment: That would be the IP address of the network card you want to use for communication. If `BoundIP` is not specified Windows try to use the network card that has fastest bandwidth. That is unless you have multiple network connections and one of them is marked as metered like for instance mobile data transfer. In such case Windows will use non-metered network connection even if it is slower.

Comment: PS: I just noticed that in your Server thread you call `AContext.Connection.Disconnect;` every time server finishes reading teh data. Is that really necessary? Without that you might be able to reuse same socket connection for sending all of your data packets instead of getting new socket connection every time client sends data packet. I'm guessing here since my experience with Indy is a bit limited.

Comment: @SilverWarior, that is called only once, when the client sends the exit code... Anyway, I tried what you said and has no effect. Then I write the same code with the NetCom7 library, but the issue persists. So the problem is not the Indy or any other library...

Comment: That would mean that the problem is on the Windows side. Why I'm not surprised?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Indy itself, or the underlying TCP connection, as evident by the fact that the TCP connection is not being cut off completely while the WiFi menu is open.

I would be more concerned over why the video shows your UI running so slowly in general. You have no sleeps in your code, nothing else running in your main UI thread, so your comms should be slamming through those 50 TCP messages in a blink, but it is not.  You are sending a *synchronous* window message to the main UI thread between each TCP message read, and it is clear in the video that there is a delay in processing each of those messages.  So, I have to assume that something external to Indy is blocking your main UI thread from handling window messages in a timely manner.  Opening the WiFi menu is simply exacerbating that issue for a few seconds.

I imagine that if you were to drop a `TTimer` (which is a window message based timer) onto your Form, set its `Interval` to a short value, and have its `OnTimer` event display a counter on your UI, you would likely see those updates appear delayed, as well.

If you get rid of the `SendString()` calls inside of the `TIdTCPServer`'s reading loop (or at least replace `SendMessage()` with `PostMessage()`) so that the loop is not being blocked by the UI at all, and then have your client send a `Cmd=0` message (or disconnect) after sending its 50 `Buff` messages so that the reading loop terminates, you *should* see the `Server STOP` message appear in your UI very quickly.  Transmitting ~100 MB of data should not take more than a few seconds on modern networking hardware.

Comment: It takes 16 seconds to transfer 100 MB on my computer, because the network through which I connect to the internet is 100 Mbps and the wireless connection between my laptop and my router it is even slower... at about 6 MB/s. So this is my real speed, is not something from the application code.

Comment: I removed completely those two `SendString`s from the server read loop, like you said, and there is no speed change...

Comment: @MarusNebunu Your client and server are on the same machine, heck even in the same process, so why are you making the connection go through the Internet at all? But, in any case, if you have disabled the `SendString()` calls between the TCP messages, and are still seeing the same delay with the WiFi menu, then it has to be an issue inside of Windows itself.  Maybe there is a bug in Winsock when the WiFi networks are queried?  Who knows.  Ask Microsoft.  Do you have other non-Indy TCP apps that are similarly affected when the WiFi menu is displayed?

Comment: I tested on a different machine and when I access the WiFi menu, the blocking period is much shorter, under 1 second... vs 8 seconds on my main PC. It seems there is a system software problem... I don't know.

Comment: I tried the same thing with the NetCom7 library and it behaves exactly the same... ! :(

Comment: And the final test: I try transfering a file with a FTP server and FileZilla client and has exactly the same problem, the transfer is blocked for a while when I access the WiFi menu. So, definitely is something from my system...

Answer (score 0):

Play a local video file (not in a web browser) and see if it hangs during your maneuver, too. That indicates the system is in general affected, not only the network.

I use [DPC Latency Checker](https://web.archive.org/web/20180319151903/http://thesycon.de/eng/latency_check.shtml) (Deferred Procedure Calls) to see if there are spikes of (typically) device drivers that take too long. Just like the manual explains: if you find spikes, try to disable single hardware components and repeat measuring. Sadly even the majority of hardware drivers are sloppy coded, and finding alternatives is a hard task.